# select() returns that socket is ready when SIGALRM

Tags: c, linux, select

I'm sorry if this question has already sounded - could not find ... So
I have timer:

```
bzero(&rtc_act, sizeof(struct sigaction));
rtc_act.sa_handler = &rtc_handler;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &rtc_act, NULL);

rtc_timer.it_interval.tv_sec = SETTIMER_INTERVAL;
rtc_timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
rtc_timer.it_value.tv_sec = SETTIMER_VALUE;
rtc_timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &rtc_timer, NULL))
{
    printf(MSG_ERR_SETTIMER_FAIL);
    retval = RETURN_ERR_SETTIMER;
} /* if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &rtc_timer, NULL)) */
```

Also i have blocked socket:

```
if ((modbus_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    retval = RETURN_ERR_SOCKET_OPEN;
    perror(MSG_ERR_OPEN_SOCKET);
    return retval;
} /* if (modbus_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0) */

setsockopt(modbus_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*)&optval , sizeof(unsigned int));

bzero((char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)ZK91_TCP_PORT_NUMBER);

if (bind(modbus_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    perror(MSG_ERR_BIND_SOCKET);
    retval = RETURN_ERR_SOCKET_OPEN;
    return retval;
} /* if (bind(modbus_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) */

if (listen(modbus_socket, TCP_CLIENTS_COUNT) < 0)
{
    perror(MSG_ERR_LISTEN_SOCKET);
    retval = RETURN_ERR_SOCKET_LISTEN;
    return retval;
} /* if (listen(parentfd, TCP_CLIENTS_COUNT) < 0) */
```

When i try to use select()

```
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(modbus_socket, &fds);
    FD_SET(can_file, &fds);
    FD_SET(modbus_file, &fds);

    select(modbus_file + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

I get the activation select() in a few seconds, although the actual data were not available.

If you try to handle this "connection":

new_socket = accept (modbus_socket, (struct sockaddr *) & client_addr, & client_len);

then the program crashes giving the screen 10 characters from then the some memory region:

net is coming (my message)

������硨���L�

uclinux#

If I do not initialize the timer, then everything works correctly, but on a timer I can not refuse.

In what could be the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: Does select really indicate that any socket is ready for reading, or just that it has been interrupted using `errno=EINTR`?

Comment: Is `modbus_file` really the highest fd in your list? Can you add a `printf ("modbus_socket %d can_file %d modbus_file %d\n", ...);` to see which is highest?

Comment: errno == EINTR. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `errno` if `select()` fails and ignore it for `SIGALRM` interruptions.

Something like:

```
for (;;) {
    int rv = select(...);
    if (rv < 0) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;    // Was a signal
        else
            // A real error occurred
    } else {
        // Handle event
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that code equivalent to the [TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html) macro?  I know this isn't portable but the question is tagged as linux so doesn't absolutely require a portable solution.

Comment: @simonc Yeah it looks the same to me; I've never used that macro however, so I know nothing about it.  I would rather hand code complex code like this anyway, as it gives me more visibility.

Comment: Thanks. You right about select() return! No this signal will be ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You must check, after `select()` returns, *why* it returns. You can't just assume that it's saying "socket ready for reading", without checking.

The checking is done using the [`FD_ISSET()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_isset) macro, to see if the socket file descriptor is still in the ready for reading set.

If `select()` is returning due to being interrupted, it will also set `errno` to `EINTR`, and return -1. Since it normally returns the number of set descriptors in the three input sets, you should check the return value too. No need to start calling `FD_ISSET()` unless `select()` has returned a value greater than 0.